# Email Images dont show up in ThunderBird

Tags: html, image, email, thunderbird

Im sending an email with diferent images, the images are attached inside the proper mail, and called with CID, the problem is that in other mail managers it appears (Gmail, Hotmail, OutLook) but in Thunder Bird it doesnt appear, it only appears when i send it with the proper ThunderBird
ill show you the diferent codes:

ThunderBird:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;
boundary="------------090609020409030103090006"    

--------------090609020409030103090006
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<img src="cid:part4.03040206.04020800@gmail.com" width="44" border="0" height="44">

--------------090609020409030103090006
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 name="Test Viernes 2.img1.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part4.03040206.04020800@gmail.com>
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename="Test Viernes 2.img1.jpg"
```

My code:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8;
boundary="mJonE6yirRSwGqpciLxBquR=_l8nG2jcGG"

--mJonE6yirRSwGqpciLxBquR=_l8nG2jcGG
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

<IMG src=3D"cid:00003" width=3D44 height=3D44>

--mJonE6yirRSwGqpciLxBquR=_l8nG2jcGG
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
    name="Test Viernes 2.img1.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename="Test Viernes 2.img1.jpg"
Content-ID: <00003>
```

I just cant understand whats the major diference in between them, becouse i only found this problem in ThunderBird and im using thunderbird 17.0.5

Any suggestions why could this be happening, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all becouse of the Content-Type: multipart/related; thank you.